# Is there a way to combine text files using the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, merge

I am thinking looking for a way to combine all the `.txt` files in a directory into a single one `.txt` file.

Is there a way to combine text files using the Windows command line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also use the copy command, eg

```
copy *.js bigfile.txt
```

or, for specific files

```
copy file1.txt+file2.txt+file3.txt bigfile.txt
```

Comment: +1 - This also allows you to decide what order to have the combined result set in.

Comment: This included the BOM in my textfiles so I fixed it my using type commando (see DanC's answer) (http://superuser.com/a/191234/56861).

Answer (score 8):

```
type * > someotherpath/all.txt
```

The need for creating the file somewhere else is that if the new file is created on the same folder, it should be excluded from the selection.

Also, filtering by extension and using a different one for the resulting file would work. For example:

```
type *.js > all.txt
```