# copying several text files to one text file in numerical order using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

i wanted to copy files "scholar (1).txt" to "scholar (25).txt" to a single .txt file 
used the following methods:
[wikihow: Merge Text (.Txt) Files in Command Prompt](http://www.wikihow.com/Merge-Text-(.Txt)-Files-in-Command-Prompt)

`for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt`

[SU: is there a way to combine text files using the windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/191231/is-there-a-way-to-combine-text-files-using-the-windows-command-line)

`copy *.txt bigfile.txt`

also
`type *.js > all.txt`

but all files are not copied in sequential manner:

```
`C:\..\Documents\New folder>type *.txt >all.txt

 scholar (1).txt
 scholar (10).txt
 scholar (11).txt
 scholar (12).txt
 scholar (13).txt
 scholar (14).txt
 scholar (15).txt
 scholar (16).txt
 scholar (17).txt
 scholar (18).txt
 scholar (19).txt
 scholar (2).txt
 scholar (20).txt
 scholar (21).txt
 scholar (22).txt
 scholar (23).txt
 scholar (24).txt
 scholar (25).txt
 scholar (3).txt
 scholar (4).txt
 scholar (5).txt
 scholar (6).txt
 scholar (7).txt
 scholar (8).txt
 scholar (9).txt`
```

Comment: Too bad that [sort](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771264.aspx) doesn't seem to have an option to sort numerically.

Comment: To clarify what’s happening, the files *are* being copied in sequential order, just not in *numerical* order. Windows Explorer has learned how to sort in numerical order in the past decade or two, but Command Prompt still uses *lexicographical* order; i.e., dictionary order. Just as the words “ha”, “he”, “hi”, and “ho” come before the word “I”, so the numbers 10, 11, 12,…, 19 are sorted before 2. If you could rename your 1, 2, 3, …, 9 files to be named 01, 02, 03, …, 09, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
(for /l %a in (1 1 25) do @type "scholar (%a).txt")>all.txt
```

For usage inside a batch file, percent signs need to be doubled, replacing `%` with `%%`

If the total number of files is unknown, but the files are named as indicated, this code can be used

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%z in ("scholar (*).txt") do for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ("%%~nxz") do (
        set /a "num=1000000000+%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in (!num!) do endlocal & set "f[%%b]=%%~fz"
    )
    (for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('2>nul set f[') do type "%%b") > all.txt
```

This creates an array in environment that allows us to retrieve a properly numerical sorted list of the files.

Comment: Nice idea, but... "Environment variable f[ not defined"

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter, you can avoid the error mesage (now included in code), but the reason for it is that not matching files have been found